# How to implement time to live with socket.io

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, socket.io

I believe I have surfed the web enough but still cant get any resources on the topic. **How can I implement the 'time-to-live' function with [Socket.io](https://socket.io/)?**

I am using [Node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/) with [express](https://expressjs.com/).
The above mentioned `time-to-live` function is intended to work as described below:

If I specify `timeToLive = 10;` secs, clients that connect in less than 10 sec after the message is emitted should still get the message.
This function is available on some of the cloud messaging libraries like [GCM](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/).

Any online resource will appreciated.

Comment: What is `time-to-live`? Where’s the reference for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such functionality in **socket.io**. You will have to implement it yourself. Consider using an array of objects that holds **messages** and **Date.now()** of that message and loop it when a user connects. Delete any messages that are expired and emit the ones that are still **valid**.
Minimum code could be this but due to heavy use of splice it could be slow.

```
var messages = [];
var TTL = 10;


io.on('connection', function (socket) {
   for(i = 0; i < messages.length; i++)
       if(messages[i].time + TTL < Date.now())
           messages.splice(i, 1);
   socket.emit('data', messages);
});
```

Consider using **redis** or any other high performance database to also synchronize between multiple servers if you require that:

Comment: If messages are always added onto the end of the `messages` array with `.push()`, then you can assume messages are in order of timestamp so you don't have to remove messages individually.  You can just run up the array until you find a message that has not expired and remove all the ones before that at once.

Comment: Yeah I am just too lazy to actual write good code here. He can optimize it himself

Comment: Do you think a global variable `var messages = [];` will serve this purpose effectively? Or database is required?

Comment: You will have to really make sure you have wrote an optimized code and that the time is not too big because if the server goes down you will lose your messages. Also you will have to think on how you will implement this when having multiple servers in cluster mode ( multiple servers )

Comment: "If messages are always added onto the end of the `messages` array with `.push()`, then you can assume messages are in order of timestamp so you don't have to remove messages individually." That's only true if all messages have the same duration.